How should I demonstrate AWS Cognito functionality in an ecommerce portfolio project?
I'm currently using AWS Cognito to handle all of my user-based data for my portfolio project; however, I highly doubt that any recruiter wants to go through the hassle of setting up an account on my website to test certain features. I know that I could create a mock account, though I'm not exactly sure what the best way to integrate this may be, especially with AWS.
Obviously, handling actual user data would then additionally introduce data privacy concerns. That said, I do want to demonstrate that I'm familiar with AWS Cognito. I already have it setup and I was planning on adding some Lambda functions to prevent malicious API usage. It's been a pretty fun learning experience, but I don't want to overdo it in terms of what I'm going to be showing or explaining to a possible recruiter. Any advice, directly relevant or not, would be super appreciated.
So far, the only real consideration that I've had is to introduce a mock account that acts as a demonstration for the site features. The account would be able to sign in, bookmark products, potentially leave a product review or rate existing ones, etc.
